# Why is my NSRange always 0?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, calculator, nsrange

I want to implement a delete key for my calculator app.  My pseudocode for this was:

```
foo = length of current number
bar = length of current number-1

current number = current number with character at index (foo-bar) removed
```

To do this in objective-c I have tried to implement this using the NSRange function as well as the StringbyappendingString method:

```
- (IBAction)DelPressed {
if ([self.display.text length] >=2)
{

    int len = [self.display.text length];//Length of entire display

    //Add to the brainlong printing out the length of the entire display
    self.brainlog.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Len is %g",len];

    int le  = ([self.display.text length]-1);//Length of entire display - 1
    NSString *lestring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"LE is %g",le];

    //Add to the brainlog printing out the length of the display -1
    self.brainlog.text = [self.brainlog.text stringByAppendingString:lestring];    

    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(le, len);//range only includes the last character

    self.display.text = [self.display.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@" "];//Replace the last character with whitespace
}
```

The output to brainlog (ie the length of both le and len) is:

```
Len is -1.99164 Le is -1.99164
```

Hard to see, but here's an image of the number I input to the calculator using the iOS simulator:
[image: iOS sim picture]

I have tried to change the value of le (ie making it the length of the display -3 or -5 etc) and both le and len are still the same.

I have also tried to make le in reference to len:

```
    int len = [self.display.text length];//Length of entire display
    //Add to the brainlong printing out the length of the entire display
    self.brainlog.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Len is %g",len];


    int le = len-1;
```

But the values of the two are still the same.  How can I use NSRange to delete the last character of the display?

**Edit**:  Using Dustin's fix, I now have reduced a rather lengthy function into 6 lines of code:

```
    -(IBAction)DelPressed{
    if ([self.display.text length] >=2)
    {
         self.display.text = [self.display.text substringToIndes:[self.display.text length] -1];
    }
 }
```

Comment: %g is also the format specifier for double types, try using %d for int types.

Comment: What exactly is `brainlog`?  Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems like the real question here has nothing to do with `NSRange` but instead should be about how on earth you're storing the length of a string as an int and ending up with a negative float instead.  Have you tried using `NSLog(@"len is %d", len)` to verify the value of `len`?

Comment: 'brainlog' is just another 'UILabel' that logs the operators that have been pressed as well as the digits.  In this case I am using it as a print statement to see what is going wrong with my method.  I have tried the NSlog way and have gotten the same result, always a float of some sort...

Comment: Have you tried it with the proper format specifier, as adc mentioned above (i.e. `%d` instead of `%g`)?

Comment: The %g was causing an issue but I have update my answer with an easier way I found using Dustin's method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `substring` instead; it's much better if all you want to do is remove the last character.

More specifically, `substringToIndex(/*length-1*/)`

Check [this reference](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_String_Objects_in_Objective-C#Searching_for_a_Substring) out if you need to do other things with strings