# Foundation crash report, no clue

Tags: ios, crash, crash-reports

I have a crash report from crashlytics about a crash happening several times, but I don't know from where to start with that one.
The only thing I am able to see form my app is the AppDelegate, and it looks like something is going wrong with an array but where should I look?

```
    Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x39720f46 objc_msgSend + 5
1  Foundation                     0x2bcec8e7 -[NSMutableRLEArray replaceObjectsInRange:withObject:length:] + 370
2  Foundation                     0x2bd06b6b -[NSConcreteMutableAttributedString addAttribute:value:range:] + 266
3  UIFoundation                   0x36792d07 -[NSStringDrawingTextStorage addAttribute:value:range:] + 50
4  UIFoundation                   0x3677ced7 -[NSMutableAttributedString(NSMutableAttributedStringKitAdditions) fixFontAttributeInRange:] + 1738
5  UIFoundation                   0x3677c71b -[NSMutableAttributedString(NSMutableAttributedStringKitAdditions) fixAttributesInRange:] + 186
6  UIFoundation                   0x36797c59 -[NSTextStorage invalidateAttributesInRange:] + 108
7  UIFoundation                   0x36792b27 -[NSStringDrawingTextStorage processEditing] + 66
8  UIFoundation                   0x36797995 -[NSTextStorage edited:range:changeInLength:] + 312
9  UIFoundation                   0x367970fb -[NSConcreteNotifyingMutableAttributedString edited:range:changeInLength:] + 50
10 Foundation                     0x2bcf2529 -[NSConcreteMutableAttributedString replaceCharactersInRange:withAttributedString:] + 328
11 UIFoundation                   0x3679278d -[NSStringDrawingTextStorage textContainerForAttributedString:containerSize:lineFragmentPadding:] + 72
12 UIFoundation                   0x3678ba7d __NSStringDrawingEngine + 7520
13 UIFoundation                   0x367905bb -[NSAttributedString(NSExtendedStringDrawing) boundingRectWithSize:options:context:] + 914
14 UIKit                          0x2ea2726b -[UILabel _updateScaledMetricsForRect:] + 618
15 UIKit                          0x2e700b51 -[UILabel _drawTextInRect:baselineCalculationOnly:] + 448
16 UIKit                          0x2e7684c9 -[UILabel drawTextInRect:] + 488
17 UIKit                          0x2e7682d9 -[UILabel drawRect:] + 84
18 UIKit                          0x2e76825d -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:] + 400
19 QuartzCore                     0x2e12e33d -[CALayer drawInContext:] + 228
20 UIKit                          0x2eb74689 -[_UILabelContentLayer drawInContext:] + 140
21 QuartzCore                     0x2e11765b CABackingStoreUpdate_ + 2070
22 QuartzCore                     0x2e1fccb9 ___ZN2CA5Layer8display_Ev_block_invoke + 52
23 QuartzCore                     0x2e116e39 x_blame_allocations + 88
24 QuartzCore                     0x2e116ad1 CA::Layer::display_() + 1160
25 QuartzCore                     0x2e0fa729 CA::Layer::display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 200
26 QuartzCore                     0x2e0fa3ed CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 24
27 QuartzCore                     0x2e0f9d81 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 224
28 QuartzCore                     0x2e0f9b6f CA::Transaction::commit() + 434
29 QuartzCore                     0x2e14d6e1 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 524
30 IOMobileFramebuffer            0x33050c07 IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc + 90
31 IOKit                          0x2bfea001 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 256
32 CoreFoundation                 0x2b02624d __CFMachPortPerform + 132
33 CoreFoundation                 0x2b0367cb __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 34
34 CoreFoundation                 0x2b036767 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 346
35 CoreFoundation                 0x2b034d69 __CFRunLoopRun + 1608
36 CoreFoundation                 0x2af81201 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
37 CoreFoundation                 0x2af81013 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
38 GraphicsServices               0x32a52201 GSEventRunModal + 136
39 UIKit                          0x2e74da09 UIApplicationMain + 1440
40 MyApp                          0x00264ee4 main (AppDelegate.swift:16)
41 libdyld.dylib                  0x39cc6aaf start + 2
```

Any idea how to go further with that one?

Comment: The crash appears to be related to an attributed string, so I would examine all cases where you configure them.

Comment: Also I googled for `"[NSMutableRLEArray replaceObjectsInRange:withObject:length:] + 370"` and hit [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19948394/textviewdidchange-crashes-in-ios-7).