# Removing the front character from NSMutableString

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablestring

I am trying to remove the front character of a `NSMutableString` and have tried:

```
    [str setString: [str substringFromIndex:1]] ,
    [str deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,1)]
```

and a few others. These two either remove every character or every character except for the one I am trying to remove so for example if I have the String *"-2357"* and am trying to remove the *"-"* then I get just the "-" when I should get "2357".

Am I doing something wrong, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Show actual code that you think is misbehaving along with logging of the inputs and outputs.

Comment: Both lines *do* remove the first character in the string, so what is your real code or question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of:

```
[str substringToIndex:1]
```

Do this:

```
[str substringFromIndex:1]
```

Comment: Ya sorry I mistyped I fixed it in my post

Comment: It should be substringFromIndex (small letter "s" in "string")

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the `deleteCharactersInRange` method, do this

```
NSRange range = {0,1};
[str deleteCharactersInRange:range];
```

Or, you could use `substringFromIndex` like so:

```
str = [str substringFromIndex:1];
```

---

Contrary to what you are saying, `[str deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,1)]` should work fine, I don't know why that is not working.

`[str substringToIndex:1]` will return the string from the beginning to the index 1, which is `-`. What you want is `substringFromIndex`. And as this method returns a `NSString`, you will need to assign it to `str`; just calling the method on `str` is not enough.

---

#### Edit

Using the `deleteCharactersInRange` may pose problems for some type of characters. For more information refer to this a question **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759855/how-to-remove-the-last-unicode-symbol-from-nsstring)**.

Instead, you can safely use

```
[str deleteCharactersInRange:[str rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:0]]
```

Comment: I have tried this, it removes all characters from my string and I am left with an empty String.

Comment: @user3631142, log the string both before and after. I bet it's not what you think it is.

Comment: @aksh1t, it's dangerous to remove characters by just assuming they're stand-alone and independent. I recommend `[str deleteCharactersInRange:[str rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:0]]`.

Comment: @user3631142 I wish to disagree with you on this. Both of these methods are working perfectly fine. You should try logging the strings before and after like KenThomases suggests.

Comment: @Ken Thomases : Thank you for the pointer. I stand enlightened. :) I will edit my answer to update this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove first character of the string you can use this:-

```
string = [string substringFromIndex:1];
```